# Enough bandwidth to support

Tags: web-hosting, bandwidth

I have a client that is paying $1500 per month for hosting of 1 website (1 domain name, email is hosted elsewhere).  The website is pretty low traffic.  Like, 100 unique visitors a week.  The only catch (and why it is so expensive) is that their database is 15 GB, and is replicated from the hosting company to inside my small companies office.

Inside the office, there is a desktop application that hits the internal database quite a bit.  From the website, some data is entered into THAT version of the database.  Replication keeps both databases in synch on a schedule of every 5 minutes.

My client has a T1 that runs into their office.  I want to knock out the hosting provider altogether, host their website from a server they already have (more than capable of handling this website), and dump the replication altogether.  This would save them $1500 per month, and for a company of 5, it would really make a difference to them.

Assuming I already have a backup strategy in place (way to move a copy of the DB offsite every day), what are the problems with this?

Support?  they can reboot their server as easily as the hosting provider can.
What if server goes down for good?  There is a duplicate that I can bring up in a couple of hours, and that is all the level of service they really require.

What am I missing here?  I want to save them money, but I don't want to screw them over...

EDIT:  Some of the answers and comments make it clear that I myself wasn't clear.  My client (company A, not a hosting provider) is paying company B to host their website.  The website has a database (MS SQL Server 2000) that is 15 GB.  That SQL Server DB is being replicated back to a server @ company A.

Company B is charging Company A $1500 per month for this service.

Company A already has a T1 for connectivity to the internet.  They are located inside of a run of the mill business park.

I am proposing doing away with any outside hosting, getting a DNS provider to point the website to Company A's static IP and hosting the website on a server inside Company A.  Then there would be no need for any replication at all, and they wouldn't be paying company B $1500 per month.

I hope that explains it.  I'm going to re-read and comment on all the current answers.

Really, any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: $1500/month? There are certainly plans that would support exactly what you describe (with bandwidth and disk space) on a hosted server that would save them about $1400/month.

Comment: Hi Greg -- I would completely entertain keeping the existing structure in place if I knew of a hosting company that would be ok with doing SQL Server replication.  Any pointers for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like your only risk in moving the server in-house is if your T1 goes down. If you have a backup strategy in place for that, go for it.

The other option is to co-loc your own server with your own SQL Server licence on it. Hosting companies charge a lot for hosting SQL Server databases because they have to pay per-CPU licencing for it. So they build up a powerful server to serve lots of client's databases, but then SQL Server offers no way to do useage accounting so they only way they can bill/screw you is on database size.

Sounds like the traffic is low enough on your site you can get a dual core server, a 1 CPU licence of SQL Server for a one-off cost of a few thousand dollars and then you're only paying the monthly co-loc price.

Comment: Actually, they already have the SQL Server licenses (they run it inhouse already) and they also have a new server with Windows server 2003 I believe...so they SHOULD have all the software they need already...thanks for the advice.  You made me feel better that I'm not completely insane.

Answer (score 0):

A hosting provider can monitor the server 24x7. What if the server crashes at 8 pm? I the people at the small company are not working around the clock?

Depends on the service this DB is providing. What are the requirements to its uptime?

Comment: That is very true.  But, if the server crashes @ 8 PM, and takes a few hours, even a day to get back up and going, nobody dies and they most likely wouldn't lose a client over it.  It's just not a "gotta have the 5 nines" type site.

Answer (score 0):

Database replication isn;t that expensive for bandwidth - well, assuming you're not doing a hotcopy of the entire DB files across the link that is.

Check out log shipping, or any of the supported replication options that will replicate the DB using minimal bandwidth. (you never said what the DB was, so I can't comment further there)

I would move to the new server and keep replication. At the very least, if you're really worried about data loss, then get another server in the same facility and copy across to that one - even if you copy 15Gb every 5 minutes, it'll be using non-chargeable bandwidth without even going outside the switch they're connected to.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I explained it right.  The bandwidth isn't necessarily the expensive portion.  It's the whole package, and the fact that this hosting provider is stuck in 10 year old pricing where disk space was a premium.  Plus, they just plain overcharge...

Comment: ah, I just couldn't see any other reason why it would be *so* expensive! Search around, choose a good company and just migrate to them, but you'd be no worse off than self-hosting.

Comment: BTW a T1 is pants, co-locate your server inside a (nearby) hosting facility and take advantage of their much-faster redundant connectivity.

Comment: The only problem with that is that they have a desktop app that accesses the same database.  And it is slow already, so adding latency and a bandwidth throughput cap wouldn't work.